# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to run my application and I keep getting the error listed in the title. I've read around and people have said to try changing theme to an AppCombat theme but that does not seem to be working. Here are my errors I am getting:

```
Process: com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles, PID: 3924
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles/com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
     at com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
     at com.example.jmeyer27.crazytiles.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 22 more
```

XML FILE: activity_game.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_game" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayoute>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't there an extra "e" at the end of your CoordinatorLayout?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/content_game" />
```

With

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_game" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` in build.gradle

Comment: ->>>  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1' THIS HELPED !!  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a spelling error in your layout file. Change `CoordinatorLayoute` to `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

And you have several options,

1. Change it into AppCompatActivity if you use Activity. Probably it becomes the error when it is Activity
2. For those using AndroidX Dependency. Along with changing dependencies, XML must also be changed.
   from
   `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
   to
   `<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
3. Adding dependencies
   `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and
   `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`