# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout on Samsung Galaxy Note Edge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

Only on Samsung Galaxy Note Edge(Android 5.0.1), I am getting android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout).

Currently I am using Support Library version 27.1.1

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
```

Before I have used Support Library version 26 also, but no success.

I have used the following theme in the corresponding activity:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item> <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item> <item name="textAllCaps">false</item> </style>
```

StackTrace:

```
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11] SourceFile:1280: Uncaught exception in Thread[main,5,main]
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.messaging.vzmsgs/com.messaging.mqtt.group.ui.CreateGroupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11]   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11] caused by:
09-13 09:56:43.378  3975  3975 FATAL [main,pri=-11] android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

Layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e5e5e5">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/group_bg">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/group_icon"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ico_add_group_img_white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <com.aniways.AniwaysEditText
                        android:id="@+id/group_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="@string/create_group_name_hint_txt"
                        android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxTextMessageWidth"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="#a1a1a0"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnEmoji"
                        android:layout_width="23dp"
                        android:layout_height="23dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/add_emoji"
                        android:src="@drawable/emoji_active_chooser"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/group_name" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.7dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/group_name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:background="#c3c3c3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >
                    <com.verizon.messaging.mqtt.group.ui.GroupRightChooser
                        android:id="@+id/group_right_chooser"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                         />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/admin_info"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/info"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_right_chooser"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/enhancedgroupInfoText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/enhanced_group_info_bar"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/enhancedgroupInfo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/enhancedgroupInfoText"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/select_group_bg"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_pencil"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emoji_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/contactsContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: Did you add `appcompat` dependency too? That's strange..

Comment: Hi @ʍѳђઽ૯ท, thanks for the quick reply. I have already added appcompat dependency.

Comment: Hi @JediBurrell , thanks for the quick reply. I have added more code to the question.

Comment: Can you show us the `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` or maybe `styles.xml` codes? That would be great.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท This theme is used on the corressponsing activity     <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>`

Comment: I see, but please add them to your question and don't paste them as comment. Please paste the `build.gradle` codes to look at the dependencies too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477067/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayoute

Comment: Hi @sanaebadi thanks for the reply. But I am already following whatsoever is mentioned in the link you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
Theme.AppCompat
```

To:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Or you can try adding this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```